# cannot add row to datatable primefaces 5.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I read many answers abot this issue, they say I should add an item to the list that feed the datatable and then refresh the form, but this does not work in my progect. this is my datatable:

```
<p:dataTable var="rowItem" 
             scrollable="true" 
             scrollHeight="100%"
             id="flussiGuestSummary"
             emptyMessage="nessun flusso guest selezionato"
             value="#{fileMatchMB.selectedGuests}" 
             rowKey="#{rowItem.row}">
    style="width:10px;text-align:center" />
    <p:column headerText="Date Valuta" 
              width="30">
        <h:outputText value="#{rowItem.data}">
            <f:converter
                converterId="filematch.interfaccia.CalendarConverter" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Importo"
              style="text-align: center; width:30px;">
        <h:outputText value="#{rowItem.amount}">
            <o:converter converterId="javax.faces.Number"
                         currencySymbol="#{rowItem.getCurrencySymbol()}" 
                         type="currency" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Descrizione" 
              styleClass="scrollableCell"
              style="text-align: center; width:80px;">
        <h:outputText value="   #{rowItem.descrizione}">
            <f:converter converterId="filematch.interfaccia.StringShortner" />
            <f:attribute name="shortnerActive"
                         value="#{fileMatchMB.shortnerActive}" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Causale" 
              styleClass="scrollableCell"
              style="text-align: center; width:30px;">

        <h:outputText value="   #{rowItem.causale}" 
                      width="100">
            <f:converter converterId="filematch.interfaccia.StringShortner" />
            <f:attribute name="shortnerActive"
                         value="#{fileMatchMB.shortnerActive}" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="match" 
              styleClass="scrollableCell"
              style="text-align: center; width:10px;">
        <h:outputText value="   #{rowItem.match}">
            <f:converter converterId="filematch.interfaccia.StringShortner" />
            <f:attribute name="shortnerActive"
                         value="#{fileMatchMB.shortnerActive}" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer"> 
        "#{fileMatchMB.countGuest} / #{fileMatchMB.guestList.size()} #{msg.msg_records}"
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

the code in the backing bean:

```
this.selectedGuests = selected_list;
```

I am sure selected_list is nort empty, but my datatable remains  empty, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to post more code. Post your add item method from backing bean, and the command button that triggers it

Comment: Sorry, I do not  need toad a row at a time, but I have to show the content of another list that  I get from some operations, so the code in the backing bean is that change the content of my datatable is: this.selectedGuests = selected_list; then I submit the form from the bean, maybe this is a bit dirty:                  RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
  context.execute("document.forms['frm_match'].submit()");

Comment: Ok so you are trying to update the entire dataTable with a new list from your backing bean. Did you try to update the datatable directly using RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("ID_OF_YOUR_DATATABLE") ?

Comment: Sorry still not working